# What is happening in the below two JavaScript statements?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

```
imgMonsterRun.onload = handleImageLoad;
imgMonsterRUn.onerror = handleImageError;
```

What are `handleImageLoad` and `handleImageError`?

Are they variables, or methods, or objects?

And if they are objects, what method of the object is going to run when that object is called upon?

Answer (score 5):

### Some background

`imgMonsterRun` is (we assume) an image object. At some point, it had a `src` specified, which points to where the image is to be loaded from. When you specify the `src`, the browser starts loading the image, but lets you move on with the rest of the program.

However, some programs might want to do certain things *after the image is done loading*, or perhaps if an *error occurs while the image is being loaded*.

To do that, you use **event handlers**. An "event" describes something happening, such as the image being loaded or an error occurring. The event **handler** is a **function** that gets called when the event **fires** ("happens").

---

### Your code

One way to attach an event handler to, say, the `load` event of an image (`imgMonsterRun` as an example) is using:

```
imgMonsterRun.onload = handleImageLoad;
```

`handleImageLoad` is expected to be a function. For instance, you can define:

```
function handleImageLoad() {
    console.log("Image loaded!");
}
```

And that will log "Image loaded!" when the `onload` event fires (presumably when the image `imgMonsterRun` is done loading).

---

### More detail

In JavaScript, functions are first-class objects. This means that they can be passed around and dealt with as if they were *"ordinary"* objects.

So, when you're assigning `handleImageLoad` to `imgMonsterRun.onload`, `imgMonsterRun.onload()` becomes effectively equivalent to `handleImageLoad()`.

---

### Try it!

To get a good grasp on this concept, try stuff like this:

```
function foo() {
    alert("Hi! I'm foo.");
}

var bar = foo; // The "reference" to the `foo` function is now assigned to `bar`.
// `bar` is now a function, too.

bar(); // This will alert "Hi! I'm foo."
```

Answer (score 2):

### What they are

They are functions.  They are called handlers because they handle a specific event, like `load` or `change`.  Notice some browsers instead use `onload` or `onchange` instead of the simpler forms.

### What makes them special

Event handlers are, by definition, asynchronous.  In other words, they can "happen any time."  If, for example, an image loads quickly, the `load` event handler will be called almost immediately.  Alternately, if there is a network error, the `load` event may never happen.

Also, and this is very important, *event handlers get receive an `event` object as their first argument*.  This object has lots of valuable information about the event.  I have updated the fiddle so you can see it.

### What they are used for

We often do not want something to happen until after some other action has occurred.  For example, we do not want to copy the bitmap of an image into a canvas until it has loaded, or an image to show until after a link has been clicked.

### Why this example is bad form

Generally, this form is deprecated.  Instead of assigning a single handler, experienced JavaScript developers generally prefer to instead attach listeners for these events.  This provides greater flexibility and prevents the 'load', 'click', 'change' or other handlers from getting accidentally clobbered (e.g. replaced) by another somewhere else in the code.

### Try it!

Here is a fiddle that shows how to do this: http://jsfiddle.net/2em7T/14/

### Here is how to attach multiple handlers to an event

This is the code from the fiddle:

```
// BEGIN x-browser utility /addListener/
// Supports IE8 with alternate function name
//  
var addListener = (function () {
  var add_fn_str, prefix_str, add_listener;

  add_listener = function ( dom_el, event_type, func ) { 
    if ( ! add_fn_str ) { 
      if ( dom_el.addEventListener ) { 
        prefix_str = '';
        add_fn_str = 'addEventListener';
      }   
      else if ( dom_el.attachEvent ) { 
        prefix_str = 'on';
        add_fn_str = 'attachEvent';
      }   
      else {
        console.warn( '_error_', '_no_means_to_add_listeners_' );
        return false;
      }   
    }

    dom_el[ add_fn_str ]( prefix_str + event_type, func );
    return true;
  };  

  return add_listener;
}());
// END x-browser utility /addListener/

var imgMonsterRun = new Image();
var handleImageLoad = function ( event) { 
  console.log( 'foo', event ); 
};
var handleImageLoad2 = function ( event ) { 
  document.body.appendChild( imgMonsterRun );
  console.log( event );
};                         

addListener( imgMonsterRun, 'load', handleImageLoad  ); 
addListener( imgMonsterRun, 'load', handleImageLoad2 );  

imgMonsterRun.src = 'http://www.tmlcustomgifts.com/1TML_Logo_2_12.jpg';
```

### How it works

Once the ImgMonsterRun image element source is loaded, 'foo' is logged to the console by one handler, and the second handler appends the image to the body. Notice you may add as many listeners the load of the image as you like using this approach, which can be quite handy.

### In summary

So there you are: an explanation, and the preferred method of implementation :)

Comment: Your `addListener` implementation is definitely quite useful, especially if vanilla JavaScript is desired (vs. using a library such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) or similar). However, it seems like the original question concerns the assignment's right-hand operand and its nature, rather than the event handling itself. If you can, please edit your answer to focus on that!

Comment: @chris: I focused the response to the right-hand operand directly in the first part of the response.  The second part of the response shows how to avoid using this practice, which is generally considered to the method shown.  I feel both parts are relevant and useful.

Comment: Your answer is your answer — compose it as you deem appropriate. However, it is worth mentioning that your statement about `.on[event] = function`-style event handling is deprecated is false. It is **not** deprecated technically ([see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onclick)). Whether it's "better" or not is utterly subjective — and talking about "current developers" seems like a bit of a generalization.

Comment: If you look at the JavaScript source code of many of Google's services' Web interfaces, you will see plenty of handlers being attached using `.on[event]` assignment. What would be the standard for "current Web developers" that Google Web frontend developers wouldn't fit? However, it is still your answer — this is only for purposes of clarification.

Comment: Just because some recent grad at Google does it doesn't mean its a good idea. I've seen lots of good practice come out of Google, and some bad stuff too.  Also, notice that I said *generally* this form is deprecated, and I think that is certainly a fair statement.  Are there uses for it?  Maybe.  But usually adding a listener is a better choice.

Comment: Thanks for your response. All I'm saying if the only basis for saying that it's "bad" or "deprecated" is observations in the wild, then I think citing major Web applications as examples is a valid thing to do. If it's merely a subjective preference/claim, I think there's no reason to discuss any further.